# jQuery UI, cookie

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I have a form of search, with more selected, checkboxes, inputs(jQuery UI).

How can I save the chosen elements by cookie, that after pressure of submit, I could change one value, but not to choose everything anew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use cookies for this you could use jQuery cookies plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
Create session cookie:
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');

 Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });

 Create expiring cookie, valid across entire page:
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });

 Read cookie:
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => 'the_value'
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => null

 Delete cookie by passing null as value:
$.cookie('the_cookie', null);
```

Comment: I know, I do not know how to connect with jQuery UI

Comment: You have to clairfy your question.

Comment: how to walk on all of form, and memorize the chosen elements? That at the update of page, the chosen elements remained chosen